# Python plot line linking values seems circle back from last point to the first one

Tags: python, plot

I met a python plotting problem. Looks like the line I plotted circles back from the last value point to the first one, so the line is a closed one, without two opening ends. Difficult to describe, I uploaded a image here:
[image: circle plot]

here is related code:

```
plt.plot(newx, newy0Normalized, color='red', linewidth=2, marker='1');
plt.plot(newx, newy1Normalized, color='green', linewidth=2, marker='2');
```

where newx is integers in the range of 50-200 and newy0Normalized is corresponding percentages

How newx and newy0Normalized are generated is a bit long. I print the data here so you know what the data (and structure) looks like:

```
for i in range(len(newx)):
    print "%d\t%.2f" % (newx[i], newy0Normalized[i])
100 7.69
101 14.81
102 9.09
103 8.33
more data here
135 40.00
136 60.00
137 50.00
139 0.00
66  100.00
67  0.00
68  0.00
69  0.00
more data here
97  11.54
98  14.81
99  11.11
```

Comment: You need to provide a complete example with actual data that shows the problem.

Comment: see my edition with some data points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how matplotlib's line plotting works: it starts with the first data point in the list, then draws a line to the next data point in the list, and so on, until it gets to the last point in the list. It's not a closed loop, though; note the break in the middle of the graph between x = 99 and x = 100. In your case, your data jumps from x = 139 to x = 66 in the middle of the list, so matplotlib will accordingly draw a line from the point at x = 139 to the point at x = 66.

If you don't want this to happen, just sort the data points by their x coordinate before plotting them. Or you can plot them as points without a connecting line, by using the `','` or `'.'` format specifier. (On scientific grounds, in most cases I would suggest the latter, but which one is correct depends on the interpretation of your data of course.)

Comment: This explains! Thanks. Shall come back later.

Comment: that's the root reason. I removed the circling line after sorting (along with some other changes). accept your answer.